# ASP.NET Include cookies in web browser cache

Tags: asp.net, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie, httpcookie

I have a website that asks for a user's location and then stores it in a cookie.  I want to add caching on the website so any requests to the same url/querystring/cookie will use the client's browser cache first.  I can make this work for server caching by using the `varyByCustom` in my `outputCacheProfiles` and creating a custom string for each request on the server.  I can't find any way to force the user to request new versions of each page after they update their cookie with a new location, without requiring them to hit the "Refresh" on their browser.

**How can I include a cookie as a dependency for a web browser's client cache?**

Here is what I am doing currently, which works for caching the different url/querystring/cookie combos on the server.

in web.config.

```
<system.web>
...
    <caching>
      <outputCacheSettings>
        <outputCacheProfiles>
          <add name="DefaultCacheProfile" enabled="true" duration="60"  varyByCustom="latlon" varyByParam="None" />
        </outputCacheProfiles>        
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
```

to use the profile on my page...

```
<%@ OutputCache CacheProfile="DefaultCacheProfile" %>
```

in global.asax.cs (`CookieSupport` is my internal class for reading my cookie)

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(System.Web.HttpContext context, string custom)
{

    if (custom.ToLower() == "latlon") {
        if (CookieSupport.CookieExists) {
            double lon = double.Parse(CookieSupport.CookieValueGet("lon"));
            double lat = double.Parse(CookieSupport.CookieValueGet("lat"));

            string varystring = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", Request.QueryString, lat, lon);

            return varystring;
        } else {
            return Request.QueryString.ToString;
        }
    }

    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
}
```

Here is how I create my cookie...

```
System.Web.HttpCookie oCookie = new System.Web.HttpCookie(CookieSupport.CookieName);
oCookie.Values.Add("lat", data_Lat.ToString);
oCookie.Values.Add("lon", data_Lng.ToString);    
Response.Cookies.Add(oCookie);
```